# Simultaneously hold down two keyboard keys to change the size of a graphic in my VS MFC graphics assignment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I'll try to be as clear as I can here. I have this C++ code here that lets me move a shape (circle or square) around  a window by clicking (selecting) once on the shape, and then tapping or  holding the arrow keys, and it let's me re-size the shape by clicking (selecting) once on the shape and tappping or holding the '+' or '-' keys.

```
   //For extra credit, modify the project so that moving the mouse with the 
   //left button and the shift key down will change the size of the selected 
   // object.

    afx_msg void CLab09Win::OnKeyDown (UINT achar, UINT repeat, UINT flags) {
        CRect modified;
        switch(achar) {
        case 'B': // 'b'
            design.SetColor ('B');
            break;
        case 38: //up arrow to move shape
            modified = design.MoveShape(0, -1);
            InvalidateRect(modified);
            break;
        case 40: //down arrow to move shape
            modified = design.MoveShape(0, 1);
            InvalidateRect(modified);
            break;
        case 107: // '+' (numeric pad) to grow shape
            modified = design.ResizeShape(2);
            InvalidateRect(modified);
            break;
        case 109: // '-' [numeric pad] to shrink shape
            modified = design.ResizeShape(-2);
            InvalidateRect(modified);
            break;
        
        };
    }
```

I want to simultaneous hold two keys to resize the shape, i.e hold 'X' and 'W', as in x + w or like how we copy something ( Ctrl + C ).
I tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
case 'X':    
if (achar == 'W') {      
   modified = design.ResizeShape(2);
   InvalidateRect(modified);
   break;
}
```

I've had a hard time finding solutions to this online because most solutions use something called VK (virtual keys), and in this assignment we don't use VK.

Ultimately, I actually want to have it so that after selecting a shape, and holding down the SHIFT key while holding the left mouse button and moving the cursor the shape will be re-sized, similar to how you re-size a window by clicking on its edge and dragging the cursor.

My code for handling mouse movement and left-button events is the following:

```
afx_msg void CLab09Win::OnLButtonDown(UINT flags, CPoint point) {
   CRect selected = design.SelectShape(point.x, point.y);
   current = point;
   InvalidateRect(selected);
}
afx_msg void CLab09Win::OnMouseMove(UINT flags, CPoint point) {
   if (flags == MK_LBUTTON) {
     int deltax = point.x - current.x;
     int deltay = point.y - current.y;
     CRect modified = design.MoveShape(deltax, deltay);
     current = point;
     InvalidateRect(modified);
  }
}
```

So to recap, I would like advice on how to use two keyboard keys [ x + w ] , and how to use a keyboard key along with the mouse's left-button [ SHIFT + LButton ] and the movement of the cursor to resize a shape (circle or square).

Thank you all.

Comment: You can use [GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) to check if a key is pressed. That takes a virtual key code as argument, indeed, but it is the same as the character value (ASCII code) for letter keys like `'X'` or `'W'` as noted in the official docs at [Keyboard Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/keyboard-input).

Comment: Try processing both OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp. You know you have two different keys pressed when you have two key down events without an intervening key up. Keep track of keys that are currently down.